# SSh tunneling over WiFi

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, ssh, tunnel

I have a PC with a WiFi adapter. I use SSH tunnelling on that PC. Now I want to share my Internet connection on that PC via the WiFi card to my other device,i.e., I want a way to send traffic via SSH tunnel to WiFi, for example, create a LAN connection over SSH and then share it through WiFi.

Internet => PC => SSH tunnel => WiFi => other devices

Is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: Doesn't the operating system provide for this kind of sharing? Routing packets between two interfaces usually happens at a lower level than `ssh` operates on. I'm not saying it's impossible, but it's certainly not something `ssh` was designed for.

Comment: is it possible to make a vpn like connection for ssh tunnel? then I think I could be able to use that connection.